# Issue detecting PCSCvia java program on linux, the card reader is connected

Tags: java, linux, smartcard, pcsc, fedora-25

I have been messing with this issue for a recent few days.

I am trying to connect a ACR122U smart card reader with fedora 25 64bit.
I am getting card in `unknown status error` which is suprising, since same smart card is working on another system with 64bit Red Hat.

Here is what I got from gpg command :

```
gpg -v --card-status
gpg: detected reader `ACS ACR122U 00 00'
gpg: reader slot 0: not connected
gpg: reader slot 0: active protocol: T1
gpg: slot 0: ATR=3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
gpg: apdu_send_simple(0) failed: unknown status error
Please insert the card and hit return or enter 'c' to cancel:
```

And this is the output of `pcscd -f -d` :

```
pcscd -f -d
00000000 debuglog.c:289:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
00000099 configfile.l:282:DBGetReaderListDir() Parsing conf directory: /etc/reader.conf.d
00000017 configfile.l:358:DBGetReaderList() Parsing conf file: /etc/reader.conf.d/libccidtwin
00000029 configfile.l:319:DBGetReaderListDir() Skipping non regular file: ..
00000004 configfile.l:319:DBGetReaderListDir() Skipping non regular file: .
00000005 pcscdaemon.c:655:main() pcsc-lite 1.8.20 daemon ready.
00003815 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/001
00000206 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0003, path: /dev/bus/usb/003/001
00000218 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000125 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000134 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000154 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x072F, PID: 0x2200, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000010 hotplug_libudev.c:433:HPAddDevice() Adding USB device: ACS ACR122U
00000048 readerfactory.c:1079:RFInitializeReader() Attempting startup of ACS ACR122U 00 00 using /usr/lib64/pcsc/drivers/ifd-acsccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/libacsccid.so
00000284 readerfactory.c:954:RFBindFunctions() Loading IFD Handler 3.0
00000030 ifdhandler.c:2611:init_driver() Driver version: 1.1.4
00000211 ifdhandler.c:2628:init_driver() LogLevel: 0x0003
00000007 ifdhandler.c:2639:init_driver() DriverOptions: 0x0000
00000008 ifdhandler.c:2647:init_driver() ACSDriverOptions: 0x0003
00000006 ifdhandler.c:2655:init_driver() ACR38CardVoltage: 0
00000006 ifdhandler.c:2663:init_driver() ACR38CardType: 0
00000038 ifdhandler.c:121:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() Lun: 0, device: usb:072f/2200:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000018 ccid_usb.c:313:OpenUSBByName() Using: /usr/lib64/pcsc/drivers/ifd-acsccid.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
00000202 ccid_usb.c:331:OpenUSBByName() ifdManufacturerString: Advanced Card Systems Ltd.
00000006 ccid_usb.c:332:OpenUSBByName() ifdProductString: ACS CCID driver
00000007 ccid_usb.c:333:OpenUSBByName() Copyright: This driver is protected by terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1, or (at your option) any later version.
00002872 ccid_usb.c:715:OpenUSBByName() Found Vendor/Product: 072F/2200 (ACS ACR122U)
00000009 ccid_usb.c:717:OpenUSBByName() Using USB bus/device: 1/3
00000007 ccid_usb.c:891:OpenUSBByName() bNumDataRatesSupported is 0
01104760 ifdhandler.c:266:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() dwFeatures: 0x00020040
00000016 ifdhandler.c:267:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() wLcdLayout: 0x0000
00000004 ifdhandler.c:268:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bPINSupport: 0x00
00000003 ifdhandler.c:269:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() dwMaxCCIDMessageLength: 271
00000002 ifdhandler.c:270:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() dwMaxIFSD: 256
00000003 ifdhandler.c:271:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() dwDefaultClock: 4000
00000004 ifdhandler.c:272:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() dwMaxDataRate: 250000
00000004 ifdhandler.c:273:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bMaxSlotIndex: 0
00000011 ifdhandler.c:274:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bCurrentSlotIndex: 0
00000020 ifdhandler.c:275:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bInterfaceProtocol: 0x00
00000006 ifdhandler.c:276:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bNumEndpoints: 3
00000002 ifdhandler.c:277:CreateChannelByNameOrChannel() bVoltageSupport: 0x07
00000006 ifdhandler.c:443:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFB3, usb:072f/2200:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/003 (lun: 0)
00000004 readerfactory.c:395:RFAddReader() Using the reader polling thread
00000650 ifdhandler.c:443:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFAE, usb:072f/2200:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/003 (lun: 0)
00000014 ifdhandler.c:543:IFDHGetCapabilities() Reader supports 1 slot(s)
00000283 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000273 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0C45, PID: 0x6A04, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00000187 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0C45, PID: 0x6A04, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00000136 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000147 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0CF3, PID: 0x0036, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/007
00000014 ifdhandler.c:1320:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:072f/2200:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/003 (lun: 0)
00000164 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0CF3, PID: 0x0036, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/007
00000131 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000136 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0BDA, PID: 0x0129, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/006
00000127 hotplug_libudev.c:294:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000043 readerfactory.c:1420:RFWaitForReaderInit() Waiting init for reader: ACS ACR122U 00 00
00000264 eventhandler.c:286:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_POWERED
00000010 Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A 
05018846 ifdhandler.c:1320:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerDown, usb:072f/2200:libudev:0:/dev/bus/usb/001/003 (lun: 0)
00000451 eventhandler.c:479:EHStatusHandlerThread() powerState: POWER_STATE_UNPOWERED
```

I am not able to get list of Terminals from `javax.smartcardio` api.

```
Terminals: []
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
```

Now the RedHat 64bit `pcscd -d-f` working fine output is this :

```
[root@localhost ~]# pcscd -f -d
00000000 pcscdaemon.c:267:main() pcscd set to foreground with debug send to stderr
00000047 debuglog.c:239:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
00004950 pcscdaemon.c:506:main() pcsc-lite 1.5.2 daemon ready.
00041789 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x072F, PID: 0x2200
00000008 hotplug_libhal.c:342:HPAddDevice() Adding USB device: usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0
01000735 readerfactory.c:1024:RFInitializeReader() Attempting startup of ACS ACR122U 00 00 using /usr/lib64/pcsc/drivers/ifd-acsccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/libacsccid.so
00000445 readerfactory.c:877:RFBindFunctions() Loading IFD Handler 3.0
00000054 ifdhandler.c:2335:init_driver() Driver version: 1.0.4
00000492 ifdhandler.c:2348:init_driver() LogLevel: 0x0003
00000319 ifdhandler.c:2368:init_driver() DriverOptions: 0x00C0
00000342 ifdhandler.c:2395:init_driver() ACR38CardVoltage: 0
00000308 ifdhandler.c:2402:init_driver() ACR38CardType: 0
00000014 ifdhandler.c:94:IFDHCreateChannelByName() lun: 0, device: usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0
00001219 ccid_usb.c:375:OpenUSBByName() Manufacturer: Advanced Card Systems Ltd.
00000307 ccid_usb.c:385:OpenUSBByName() ProductString: ACS CCID driver
00000354 ccid_usb.c:391:OpenUSBByName() Copyright: This driver is protected by terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1, or (at your option) any later version.
00004398 ccid_usb.c:649:OpenUSBByName() Found Vendor/Product: 072F/2200 (ACS ACR122U)
00000004 ccid_usb.c:651:OpenUSBByName() Using USB bus/device: 003/009
00000255 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000004 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000010 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000002 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
00000001 ccid_usb.c:1402:get_data_rates() declared: 0 bps
01001133 ifdhandler.c:220:IFDHCreateChannelByName() dwFeatures: 0x00020040
00000025 ifdhandler.c:221:IFDHCreateChannelByName() wLcdLayout: 0x0000
00000011 ifdhandler.c:222:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bPINSupport: 0x00
00000009 ifdhandler.c:223:IFDHCreateChannelByName() dwMaxCCIDMessageLength: 271
00000008 ifdhandler.c:224:IFDHCreateChannelByName() dwMaxIFSD: 256
00000008 ifdhandler.c:225:IFDHCreateChannelByName() dwDefaultClock: 4000
00000008 ifdhandler.c:226:IFDHCreateChannelByName() dwMaxDataRate: 250000
00000007 ifdhandler.c:227:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bMaxSlotIndex: 0
00000009 ifdhandler.c:228:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bCurrentSlotIndex: 0
00000007 ifdhandler.c:229:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bInterfaceProtocol: 0x00
00000008 ifdhandler.c:230:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bNumEndpoints: 3
00000008 ifdhandler.c:231:IFDHCreateChannelByName() bVoltageSupport: 0x07
00000018 ifdhandler.c:536:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFB0, usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0 (lun: 0)
00000009 readerfactory.c:249:RFAddReader() Using the pcscd polling thread
00000657 ifdhandler.c:536:IFDHGetCapabilities() tag: 0xFAE, usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0 (lun: 0)
00000023 ifdhandler.c:630:IFDHGetCapabilities() Reader supports 1 slot(s)
00001000 ifdhandler.c:1354:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0 (lun: 0)
00000940 Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A 
00021088 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8000
00000457 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002
00001725 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x8008
00000487 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002
00000799 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0003
00000486 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x07DC
00000440 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x07DC
00000535 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x058F, PID: 0x9540
00000537 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x28C8, PID: 0x4702
00000381 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x28C8, PID: 0x4702
00000459 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x1C7A, PID: 0x0603
00000491 hotplug_libhal.c:307:get_driver() Looking a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002

99999999 eventhandler.c:361:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card Removed From ACS ACR122U 00 00
01969317 ifdhandler.c:1354:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0 (lun: 0)
00109789 eventhandler.c:429:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card inserted into ACS ACR122U 00 00
00000010 Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A 
10140676 eventhandler.c:361:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card Removed From ACS ACR122U 00 00
01341945 ifdhandler.c:1354:IFDHPowerICC() action: PowerUp, usb:072f/2200:libhal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_72f_2200_noserial_if0 (lun: 0)
00051244 eventhandler.c:429:EHStatusHandlerThread() Card inserted into ACS ACR122U 00 00
00000010 Card ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A 



WHEN REMOVING CARD READER ---------

00000034 ccid_usb.c:950:WriteUSB() usb_bulk_write(003/010): No such device
00000045 readerfactory.c:914:RFUnloadReader() Unloading reader driver.
```

Comment: Is that output from gpg from the system where your application does not work (i.e. fedora 25 64bit)? Does listing terminal through `javax.smartcardio` work on the RedHat 64bit machine? What Java versions do you use on the two machines?

Comment: yes its working on RedHat64bit with oracle-jdk7 and not on fedora25 with oracle-jdk-8u111

Comment: Okay, so you are using different JDK versions. Do you use 64-bit versions of the JRE for running the application on both? How do you instantiate the TerminalFactory in your application? Do you use `TerminalFactory.getDefault()`? If yes, what terminal factory do you get (i.e. what values do you get for `terminalFactory.getType()`, `terminalFactory.getProvider().getName()`, and `terminalFactory.getProvider().getInfo()`)?

Answer (score -1):

PC/SC Lite states [here](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/unsupported.html), that your reader is not supported:

> Time extension requests are not supported.
>
> Firmwares version < 2.06 are bogus: APDU with 0x7B (123) bytes
>   expected do not work with a 14443 card. The reader returns SW=63 00
>   instead.
>
> See http://www.average.org/pcsclite-ACR122U/ for a workaround to be
>   used with my CCID driver
>
> The firmware 2.14 may report bStatus = 0x00 indicating No Error but
>   with bError = 0xFE indicating ICC_MUTE, CCID timed out while talking
>   to the ICC. See https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pyscard/issues/18

There is a workaround available: http://www.average.org/pcsclite-ACR122U/

Also I noticed in your RedHat log driver version `1.0.4` is loaded:

```
ifdhandler.c:2335:init_driver() Driver version: 1.0.4
```

In your fedora log driver version `1.1.4` is loaded:

```
ifdhandler.c:2611:init_driver() Driver version: 1.1.4
```

Maybe try to update to the [newest version](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/CCID) (`1.4.26`) before doing the workaround.

Comment: appriciate your effort,but updation is already done and not the ulimate solution.

Comment: Yes and what about the fact, that the reader is listed under not supported devices? Because some of them may have faulty or non CCID compliant firmware?

Comment: The ACS Vendor provides its own CCID for its products.